# Set selected spinner item based on a name, not a position in Android

Tags: android, database, position, set, spinner

I have three spinners in an activity where I can edit information that the user has already entered into a database. I have been able to set the text of a textfield by querying my SQLite database to match what the user can edit. Can the same be done with a spinner?

For example, if a user picked the year 2000 previously, in the new edit activity I want the spinner to be already selected at 2000 and then they can change this if they want to.

So far I have only seen options to set positions of spinners based on an integer position. Can this be done by providing a year? Thanks for any help.

Here's what I am currently working on with my month spinner:

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months)) );
int pos = list.get("March");
spinMonth.setSelection(pos);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All you can do is identifying the position of the item in the spinner and the setting the selection of spinner.

```
int pos=yourlist.indexOf("2000");

spinner.setSelection(pos);
```

**Edit:**

```
ArrayList<String> list=new ArrayList( Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.years)) );  // your array id of string resource
int pos= list.indexOf("2000");
spinner.setSelection(pos);
```

Comment: @colmulhall I have edit my answer based on the above comment, use that code

Comment: One of my spinners is populated using an array of months from strings.xml. The below code will not work for me:          ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList( Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months)) );
        int pos = list.get("March");
        spinMonth.setSelection(pos);

Comment: @colmulhall it is `indexOf("March")` not `get("March")` I have edited my answer, it was just typing mistake

Answer (score 0):

I had to do the exact same thing the other week. Here was my approach.

```
String userName = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex("USER_NAME"));
int position = listOfUsers.indexOf(userName);
userSpinner.setSelection(position);
```

where `listOfUsers` is the list I use to popular the Spinner, `userSpinner`. Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks this is near to what I am looking for. I populate my spinner with an array in my strings.xml file. Do you know how I can use this as you use "listOfUsers" in your example? Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Simple one line code is

```
spinMonth.setSelection(Arrays.asList(getResources().getStringArray(R.array.months)).indexOf("March"));
```

Comment: One of the purposes of using string resources is for localization. This one line of code will break if you support different languages.